# How do I update upload a new version of my widget in Oracle Commerce Cloud?

Tags: oracle, oracle-commerce-cloud

I'm able to upload a widget as part of a new extension, but if I want to make changes to that widget and upload a new version I'm not able to. When I try to re-upload the widget, its throwing:

```
Extension was not installed The following errors were found:
Widget WidgetTemplate already exists.
Extension ID already exists.
```

Where `WidgetTemplate` is the name of my widget. I've updated the version in ext.json but it made no difference. I'm able to edit the css, js, and template through the design section, but im not able to add elements for example.

Is there a way to upload a new version of an existing widget, or do I need to create a new extension for each new widget version?

Answer (score 0):

You have to first deactivate the widget which you want to change and then reupload the widget

You can go for steps

- 1)Select Setting tab
- 2)Click Extension
- from there go for installed section then search the widget you want
  to deactivate

  and then after deactivating it will ask for delete so after doing these two steps upload the widget with your changes and then drag that were you want to apply

Answer (score 0):

Elements are uploaded in a separate way. 
You can either create a stand-alone element or widget-specific element.
Follow the below link to understand how to create and upload an element
[Creating and uploading and element in OCC](https://videohub.oracle.com/media/Technical+Dives+with+Commerce+CloudA+Widget+Elements/1_ziwzwm6y)

For reuploading a widget you need to first deactivate then delete the previous widget from settings>extensions.
Also, if you don't want to delete the previously uploaded widget then change the widget name and update the same in widget.json of it and create a new extension id with a different name. [IMP: NAMES MUST SYNC WITH EACH OTHER]

Hope this answer is quite helpful. :)